# How to prevent reload from disk when using open() in Python?

Tags: python, printing, truncate, overwrite, txt

This is my first post on StackOverflow. I'm also a beginner in Python. So I was just tinkering with the open() function, I was making a simple program to replace text in other .txt files. Here is my code:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r+")

f.truncate(0)
f.write("This text has been replaced.")
f.close()
print("Text replaced")
```

So, after running this program, the text in "file.txt" is getting changed. However, when I do ctrl + z, it's showing Undo Reload from Disk?, and when you click OK, the text gets back to normal.

How to prevent this? I am using Python 3.9, Pycharm code editor.

Thank you

Comment: I can't believe it... it's impossible... so-so-somebody took the username "Python"?

Comment: If all you want to do is overwrite the contents of a file, use `'w'`, not `'r+'`, as the mode. Then you don't need to call `truncate` at all; truncation is part of the definition of opening a file in write mode.

Comment: Python is not responding to Ctrl-Z. This is a question about PyCharm so I suggest you tag your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I think your question might be more about the PyCharm UI editor.

If I understand correctly:

1. you have "file.txt" open in the PyCharm editor
2. you run the code above

At this point, the filesystem has the "file.txt" with the updated contents.  The PyCharm editor (buffer) still has the old contents.

When you ctrl+z, PyCharm notices the filesystem has been updated and prompts to see how you want to proceed.  When you click "OK", PyCharm writes its buffer to the file, which is the original contents.

Comment: So if I don't use PyCharm, it will work as intended?

Comment: It's already working as intended. I'm not sure why you think an entirely separate program taking it upon itself to do something else is related to your program.

Comment: Yes.  If you don't have "file.txt" open in the PyCharm editor, the editor buffer will not be out of sync with the filesystem.  If you can run from the DOS prompt:  1) type file.txt  2) python3 <yourcode.py> 3) type file.txt.   You will see your code working as expected.